# Document Create Full Element

Tags: javascript

I'm making a little app, which has to append 3 elements to another element, by using this code:

```
var MyElem1= document.createElement("div");
ParentElem.appendChild(MyElem1);
```

This works just fine, but i was wondering if there is a way to create a full element, like this for example:

```
var MyElem1= document.createElement('<div style="some-styling: here;">Some InnerHtml Here</div>');
    ParentElem.appendChild(MyElem1);
```

I know i can add those properties to the element after i create it, but i'm hopping there's a way to do it inline like that (Something that works cross-browser).

I saw on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) (yes i know i should stop using it) the `createElement` function requires only the element type (div, span, button, etc...).

Comment: Not really, you can set the `innerHTML` of another element to a string, but why would you when you can use `createElement` instead. Just add the properties and attributes to each element.

Comment: No, there's no way to do like that.

Comment: @adeneo Yes i know i can add the properties for each element, but there are quite a few of them, and they take quite a lot of space.

Comment: @Adrao, have you tried `.outerHTML` ?

Comment: Space, as in the size of the code, shouldn't be an issue, you're still going to be better of building the elements yourself than just inserting a string, and the browser parses that string and does the same thing anyway ?

Comment: @Arvind According to to http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html is not fully supported cross-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dummy container and create all elements you want inside it by replacing its `innerHTML` property, and then getting the `.firstChild`.

Here is a reusable function for it

```
var elementFactory = (function (){
   var dummy = document.createElement('div');

   return function(outerHtml){
       var node;
       dummy.innerHTML = outerHtml;
       node = dummy.firstChild;
       dummy.removeChild(node);
       return node;
   }
})();
```

and use it like this

```
var MyElem1 = elementFactory('<div style="some-styling: here;">Some InnerHtml Here</div>'),
    MyElem2 = elementFactory('<div style="some-other-styling: here;">Some Other InnerHtml Here</div>');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/5De3p/1/

Comment: @Adrao, indeed. I updated the answer to correct that (*the problem was that since DOM references are **live** they were being overwritten when creating new elements, if the previous had not been added to the DOM*)